# How do I select multiple elements having the same value using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to select all `OrderLines` with `ProductType` "Email".
Is there a 'where' clause for that. I have to use an xpath for the selection.
This is my XML document:

```html
<InputOrder>
  <Order> 
 <OrderType>Change</OrderType> 
    <OrderLine>
      <ServiceId>100001</ServiceId>
      <Product>
        <Email>          
          <ProductLine>Email</ProductLine>
          <ProductName>Email Service</ProductName>
          <ProductLevel>2</ProductLevel>
          <ProductType>EMAIL</ProductType>
          <ProductOperation>NoChange</ProductOperation>
        </Email>
      </Product>
      <Asset>        
        <ActivationStatus>Complete</ActivationStatus>
        <AssetStatus>Active</AssetStatus>
      </Asset>
      <OrderLineStatus>Open</OrderLineStatus>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <ServiceId>100001</ServiceId>
      <Product>
        <Email>          
          <ProductLine>Email</ProductLine>
          <ProductName>Email</ProductName>
          <ProductLevel>3</ProductLevel>
          <ProductType>EMAIL</ProductType>
          <ProductOperation>NoChange</ProductOperation>          
        </Email>
      </Product>
      <Asset>        
        <ActivationStatus>ReadyForActivation</ActivationStatus>
        <AssetStatus>Active</AssetStatus>
      </Asset>
      <OrderLineStatus>Open</OrderLineStatus>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <ServiceId>100001</ServiceId>
      <Product>
        <Access>
          <ProductLine>Access</ProductLine>
          <ProductName>Internet Access Service</ProductName>
          <ProductLevel>2</ProductLevel>
          <ProductType>INTERNETACCESS</ProductType>
          <ProductOperation>NoChange</ProductOperation>          
        </Access>
      </Product>
      <Asset>
        <ActivationStatus>Complete</ActivationStatus>
        <AssetStatus>Active</AssetStatus>
      </Asset>
      <OrderLineStatus>Open</OrderLineStatus>
    </OrderLine>
 <OrderLine>
      <ServiceId>100001</ServiceId>
      <Product>
        <Itv>          
          <ProductLine>TV</ProductLine>
          <ProductName>Ethernet switch</ProductName>
          <ProductLevel>3</ProductLevel>
          <ProductType>LITVADDITIONAL</ProductType>
          <ProductOperation>NoChange</ProductOperation>          
        </Itv>
      </Product>
      <Asset>
        <ActivationStatus>Complete</ActivationStatus>
        <AssetStatus>Active</AssetStatus>
      </Asset>
      <OrderLineStatus>Open</OrderLineStatus>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <ServiceId>100001</ServiceId>      
      <Product>
        <Internet>          
          <ProductLine>Internet</ProductLine>
          <ProductName>IC31</ProductName>
          <ProductLevel>3</ProductLevel>
          <ProductType>INTERNET</ProductType>
          <ProductOperation>Add</ProductOperation>         
        </Internet>
      </Product>
      <OrderLineStatus>Open</OrderLineStatus>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <ServiceId>100001</ServiceId>
      <Product>
        <Internet>         
          <ProductLine>Internet</ProductLine>
          <ProductName>IC01</ProductName>
          <ProductLevel>3</ProductLevel>
          <ProductType>INTERNET</ProductType>
          <ProductOperation>Delete</ProductOperation>          
        </Internet>
      </Product>
      <Asset>
        <ActivationStatus>Complete</ActivationStatus>
        <AssetStatus>Active</AssetStatus>
      </Asset>
      <OrderLineStatus>Open</OrderLineStatus>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <ServiceId>100001</ServiceId>
      <Product>
        <Itv>          
          <ProductLine>TV</ProductLine>
          <ProductName>Sport1 pakket</ProductName>
          <ProductLevel>3</ProductLevel>
          <ProductType>TVCHANNEL</ProductType>
          <ProductOperation>Add</ProductOperation>          
        </Itv>
      </Product>
      <OrderLineStatus>Open</OrderLineStatus>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <ServiceId>100001</ServiceId>
      <Product>
        <Itv>
          <ProductLine>TV</ProductLine>
          <ProductName>Digitale tv-ontvanger met harddiskrecorder</ProductName>
          <ProductLevel>3</ProductLevel>
          <ProductType>TV</ProductType>
          <ProductOperation>Delete</ProductOperation>
        </Itv>
      </Product>
      <Asset>
        <ActivationStatus>Complete</ActivationStatus>
        <AssetStatus>Active</AssetStatus>
      </Asset>
      <OrderLineStatus>Open</OrderLineStatus>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <ServiceId>100001</ServiceId>
      <Product>
        <Itv>
          <ProductLine>TV</ProductLine>
          <ProductName>Digitale tv-ontvanger</ProductName>
          <ProductLevel>3</ProductLevel>
          <ProductType>TV</ProductType>
          <ProductOperation>Delete</ProductOperation>          
        </Itv>
      </Product>
      <Asset>
        <ActivationStatus>Complete</ActivationStatus>
        <AssetStatus>Active</AssetStatus>
      </Asset>
      <OrderLineStatus>Open</OrderLineStatus>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <ServiceId>100001</ServiceId>      
      <Product>
        <Engineer>          
          <ProductLine>Engineer</ProductLine>
          <ProductName>Omruilen NT</ProductName>
          <ProductLevel>3</ProductLevel>
          <ProductType>ACCESSENGINEER</ProductType>
          <ProductOperation>Add</ProductOperation>         
        </Engineer>
      </Product>
      <OrderLineStatus>Open</OrderLineStatus>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <ServiceId>100001</ServiceId>
      <Product>
        <Engineer>
          <ProductLine>Engineer</ProductLine>
          <ProductName>Omruilen modem</ProductName>
          <ProductLevel>3</ProductLevel>
          <ProductType>ACCESSENGINEER</ProductType>
          <ProductOperation>Add</ProductOperation>          
        </Engineer>
      </Product>
      <OrderLineStatus>Open</OrderLineStatus>
    </OrderLine>
    <HardwareAlreadyDelivered>false</HardwareAlreadyDelivered>   
    <Leadtime>12</Leadtime>
    <DirectTerminationMailandUser>false</DirectTerminationMailandUser>    
    <SuppressCommunication>false</SuppressCommunication>
  </Order>
</InputOrder>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xpath:

```
//OrderLine[.//ProductType[text()='EMAIL']]
```

It's pretty similar to WHERE expression.

You search all `//OrderLine`, by a special condition. 
And this condition in your case is that somewhere inside should be productType, so it's `"//ProductType[text()='EMAIL']"`. Also a dot `.` should be added before it, to search for product types by relative xpath inside OrderLine, and not somewhere in the xml file.

Comment: That worked for selecting one(first) element with the text 'EMAIL' but not for all the elements that contain the text.

Comment: This xpath finds all elements that satisfy the condition. The question is what tool you use to search for it. Probably you should use something like "findAll",  etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the condition into square brackets:

```
/InputOrder/Order/OrderLine[Product/Email/ProductType="EMAIL"]
```

It's called a **predicate** in XPath.